# Difference between php sessions and home made session?

Tags: php, session, sessionid

I am trying to understand what the differences are and which is more secure? I currently send the `uid=XXX&key=XXXX` params with each call. The `uid` is generated from database and `key` randomly generated (and stored in column in database as a row key) and use apc to store the IP for security, but basically every script online relies on php sessions.

So should I be using their method instead? I don't want to re-invent the wheel and not sure if I am but I can't tell the difference between my method and regular php sessions.

Comment: It seems to me that you ought to [learn more about PHP sessions](http://php.net/sessions). If you know what PHP sessions are then it will be quite easy to answer this for yourself.

Comment: You may need to look into hashing those values for better security --- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

Answer (score 2):

Sessions uses key stored in a cookie. Putting it to url and pass that way for every GET request is not best idea for many reasons including:

1. User can share URL to someone without noticing that it contains this data
2. User can bookmark it in his browser
3. It's visible for everyone around so its prone for session hijacking
4. Some cache servers can store it
5. It can be send to other sites via referer

Do not try invent one more wheel but at the same time don't try to use squares to replace them.